# List launcher apps from Office365

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are looking to create our own "My apps" From Office365 to create a launcher.
We currently use microsoft.graph for other functionalities (like authorization) but I don't see a way to get my tenants available apps.

Using getSubscribedSkus and the users's assignedPlans / assignedLicenses we can figure it out, but that shows nothing about pinned tiles, images, urls etc.

Is there another way to get this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Applications API in preview under /beta: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications. The API is documented here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application

Comment: Apparently this is currently the only way to show Registered applications (not by any assigned license).

Answer (score 0):

> We currently use microsoft.graph for other functionalities (like authorization) but I don't see a way to get my tenants available apps.

As far as I know, there is no API to achieve this so far. You may consider submitting a User Voice on https://officespdev.uservoice.com.